# Why ca't I send serialized object back to client?

Tags: json, elasticsearch, json.net, nest

I am trying to return a resulting object back to client

The result is a list object returned by ElasticSearch

```
var results = new Hits()
            {
                Results = result.Hits.ToList() 
            };

AjaxResponse.AddJsonData("Hints", results); <-- Gives Error
```

Basically I expect a json object on the client side which I can loop through and build some UI

I have the Newtonsoft.Json.dll in my bin folder but nothing in my web.config file.
I didn't put the Newtonsoft.Json.dll in GAC

*Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)*

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the version of Library that you are referencing in the code is same as the one in the bin folder and GAC.

Comment: I see that the Version=6.0.0.0 and Runtime version v4.0.30319 but the error message is saying v4.0.0.0 Not sure where it is getting that info

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved. NuGet package manager console installation resolved it.
Somehow the command was not working earlier.